# What do the particles mean in 'believe of, on, to something'?

Tags: etymology, particles

Foreword: [The use of 'believe **of**' in this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55595/apt-preposition-into-an-organisation-which-procedures-were-being-pract#comment105011_55595), motivated this question.

> [2. intr.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17376?redirectedFrom=believe) With *in*, **†*of* (rare), †*on*, †*to* (rare)**. To have confidence in the truth or accuracy of (a statement, doctrine, etc.).
>   In later use also: to have confidence in the genuineness, virtue, value, or efficacy of (a principle, institution, practice, etc.).

Please help me dig deeper than the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy.

1. I'm habituated to 'believe in something', but please help me make sense of the rarer 'believe ***of, on, to*** something'. Which definitions  of [of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of), [on](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on), [to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to) match? These particles confuse me.

2. Does OED imply (but fail to declare) that: believe + ***of, on, to*** + something
 = 'believe in something'? Or do they differ?

Comment: I've come across a Christian usage where 'believe in' means 'give intellectual assent to' [the assertion that say Jesus lived/lives, was who He said, did what the Bible says He did; that what God says will come true ...), whereas 'believe on' means 'put your money (/life) where your mouth is' (ie follow unto death). Believe of / to a doctrine etc is, I'd say, obsolete. // A particle essentially has no independent meaning. The MWV etc it forms part of has a unitary meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*to **believe** [something] **of** [someone] = to **believe** [something] **about*** [someone]

is quite easy.

It's

**of** *preposition* : :  relating to :  with reference to :  as regards :  **about**
[M-W U]

A bit obsolete, it  mainly shows in theological works:

> [The bench and bar of Georgia: memoirs and sketches, with ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=mTpMAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA465&dq=%22believed%20of%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3Vw-Va2iBYa0yASOroHIBw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22believed%20of%20them%22&f=false) Stephen
>   Frank Miller - 1858
>
> The conduct of the British, (particularly of the officers,) both at
>   St. Simon's and St. Mary's, exceeds even what you and **I believed of
>   them** in flagitiousness. Nothing was of too little value to tempt
>   them; and every thing was grasped,

where:

fla·gi·tious·ness
:  the quality or state of being flagitious :  corruption, vice, villainy

*what you and **I believed of them** in flagitiousness* = *what you and **I believed about them** **/in terms of/with regard to/** flagitiousness*

Similarly:

*believe **on** this matter = believe **about** this matter*

I'd suggest you should buy an online subscription to the Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary ($30/year), for such things are well well treated there. The best AmE definitions, IMO. Thus spare your time.